# the argument type 'int' cannot be assigned to parameter string flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'am working on flutter and i'am able to parse my api request using dio perfectly but after Listing my item instead of saving total sum in database i want to show the user sum of two columns from database but i encounter the argument type 'int' cannot be assigned to parameter string  error here is my code

```
? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: filteredItems.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return GestureDetector(

                onTap: () {
                 
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(PostDetail.routeName, arguments: filteredItems[index]);
                },
                child: Card(

                  elevation: 10,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10, horizontal: 8),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[

                        Text(
                          filteredItems[index]['product_name'],
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          // here i need to display two columans from database but error appers here
         int.parse( filteredItems[index]['priceOne'])- int parse(filteredItems[index]['priceDisc']); 
                               
                                              
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                  ),
                ),
              );
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will definitely not display any text because the `Text` widget requries a `String`. What you'll have to do is to convert that `int` to a `String` to display it. Here is an example:

```
 Text((int.parse(filteredItems[index]['priceOne'])- int.parse(filteredItems[index]['priceDisc'])).toString()),
```

Comment: Thanks. I hope that new users would see this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't to display in Text:
`Text( int.parse( filteredItems[index]['priceOne'])- int parse(filteredItems[index]['priceDisc']); )`

You must write, for example:

```
Row(
   children: [
    Text(
filteredItems[index]['priceOne'] + ' - '),
    Text(filteredItems[index]['priceDisc'])
]
                           
  or:

          Text((int.parse(filteredItems[index]['priceOne'])- int.parse(filteredItems[index]['priceDisc'])).toString()),
```